# Как реализовать анимацию кружов?

Tags: javascript, html

ввели шесть цифр - заполнились кружками
А если ничего не ввели - то будут просто черточки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос. Какую анимацию вы хотите сделать и с помощью чего?

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь стандартным полем для ввода пароля, добавив соответствующее оформление:

```css
body { font: 600 32px/1em 'Segoe UI', monospace; color: #f7eeef; background-color: #0066b0; }

input[type="password"] {
  font: 96px/1em 'Courier New', monospace;
  height: 1em;
  width: 6ch;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #f7eeef;
  caret-color: transparent;
  background: 0.185em 0.43em / 0.6em 0.0625em linear-gradient(to right, currentColor 0 0.243em, transparent 0.243em 0.6em) repeat-x;
}
input[type="password"]::-ms-reveal { display: none; }
```

```html
Введите секретный код<br>
<input type="password" maxlength="6">
```

Comment: [Слетает на Microsoft Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s23hi.png) из-за встроенной функции показа пароля.

Comment: @eccs0103, поправил.